# GitLab configuration

Tags: configure, gitlab

I try to install Gitlab 5.2 on OS-X Server 10.8.5.  I follow the procedure document from :
    "http://thoughtpointers.net/2013/05/23/installing-gitlab-v52-on-os-x/".

In the section of the document titled "Configure GitLab" they ask to edit the file "gitlab.yml" and change  "gitlab.example.com" with the "fully qualified domain name" of your host serving Gitlab.

I dont understand what I need to change..


1. Do I need to change "host: gitlab.example.com" with "localhost" ? or with "server.local => what I get when typing "hostname") ?


2. What is "gitlab.example.com" ?  Something to download and install on my computer (so where?)?  What replace it ?


I think when I type the address on my browser :

```
    "http://fully qualified domain name"
```

I will receive a page, from where comes that page (is it an index.html/php?) - where is the folder of that page/project...


Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

By default, what you see in the [`config/gitlab.yml`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlabhq/blob/master/config/gitlab.yml.example#L18) is:

```
  ## GitLab settings
  gitlab:
    ## Web server settings
    host: localhost
    port: 80
    https: false
```

That allows you to test Gitlab locally.

If you replace:

```
host: localhost
```

with:

```
host: ip.address (192.168.x.x)
#
host: fqn (your fully qualified name)
```

Then you will be able to test / access GitLab from another computer.

So `gitlab.example.com` is an example of such a fully qualified name, and should be changed by your own.

As [explained here](https://serverfault.com/a/499900/783), check what **`host hostname`** returns.

Comment: Thank for the answer.. 

Can you tell me also in the file "config.yml" - "gitlab_url" if I need to place my IP or fqdn ?

Thk.

Comment: as an addition to this the config/gitlab.yml can be found using the command `locate gitlab.yml`